# Opening a web page with the default browser

Tags: android

is there some now system requirements for opening the default system browser on an Android device in this way:

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://google.com");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
      startActivity(intent);
    } else {
      Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, R.string.browser_not_found, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Because on Android API 33 and 34, I get the "Browser not found" toast message, instead of the page being open in the default browser, which exists and is set up.

Is there some new requirement in the newer Android versions?

Comment: Maybe you have to add mime type "text/html".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Package visibility filtering](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility?hl=en), You should add `queries` element in your AndroidManifest.

```xml
<manifest package="com.example.application">
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
    ...
</manifest>
```

Comment: No. Not for using ACTION_VIEW.

Comment: The answer is not the full solution to my problem, but it is the correct answer to my question "is there anything new", it points to the package visibility filtering, introduced in Android API 30.